# Why is multiplication and division easy, yet addition and subtraction horrible when it comes to Prime Factorisations?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

If we have a positive integer $n$ and a function $f(n)$, such that $f(n)=3n$ , we can see that the prime factorisation of $n$ simply changes to includes another 3 within its prime factorisation.

E.g $n = 12 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$ becomes $f(n)=3(12)=2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$

If we have a positive integer $n$ and a function $f(n)$, such that $f(n) = n/2$ and we stop when the end result is not a whole number, we can see that the prime factorisation of $n$ simply changes to remove another 2 within its prime factorisation.

E.g $n = 12 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$ becomes $f(n)=12/2= 2 \cdot 3$

Any function that multiplies an integer $n$ by an integer $a$ $[f(n)=a \cdot n]$ simply includes more primes to the prime factorisation of $n$ (aka, the primes of a).

Any function that divides an integer $n$ by an integer $a$ $[f(n)=a/n]$ simply removes more primes from the prime factorisation of $n$ (aka, the primes of a), given that the end result remains an integer.

This is simple. On the other hand, when there is a positive integer $n$ and a function $f(n)$, such that $f(n) = n + 1$, why does the prime factorisation of the input and output differ so much?

E.g $n = 12 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$ becomes $f(n) = 12 + 1 = 13$

Primes are supposed to be the atoms of number theory and of the natural numbers. Yet, when such a simple operation such as adding 1 is applied to any positive integer, the Prime Factorisation suddenly... changes? How can the atoms of a number just change like that? Is there any correlation between the input prime factorisation and the output prime factorisation?

Comment: factoring is a multiplicative decomposition, so how it interacts with addition is not simple

Comment: The primes are the atoms *with respect to multiplication*. A factorisation, by definition, describes what to multiply together to produce a given number, and the primes are building blocks of this process. Adding 1 is simple as far as adding is concerned, but we can't expect it to have simple results as far as factorisation is concerned.

Comment: Also, typesetting hint: try `$...$` instead of `*...*`.

Comment: Is there any way to find out the resulting prime factorisation? Sorry if it seems useless, but I'm really curious about the interactions between integers with addition

Comment: @Théophile thank you, I am new to this forum!

Comment: this is why conjectures like Goldbach's are so challenging

Comment: Welcome. :) No, there's no obvious way to know the new factorisation. Imagine a group of $60$ people who want to split into teams of equal size for a tournament. Great, maybe you can put them in $6$ groups of $10$. But now one more person shows up...

Comment: The definition of a unique factorization domain (generalization of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to other rings) has nothing to do with the ring's addition, so one could just as well define the notion of a "unique factorization monoid", where identifying associates (two elements $x$ and $y$ for which there is some invertible element $z$ for which $zx=y$) gives a free commutative monoid.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thank you!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yeah, I was also looking into one of those conjectures ;(

Comment: The only thing we know about the factors of $\ a+b\ $ : $\ \gcd(a,b)\ $ will be a divisor of $\ a+b\ $ , if we divide , we get $\ u+v\ $ with coprime $\ u\ $ and $\ v\ $ and the prime factors of $\ u+v\ $ must be distinct from those of $\ u\ $ and $\ v\ $. That's it.Only in special cases , like Mesenne-numbers or Fermat-numbers, we have additional restrictions. Even a primality test is not easy, even if we know the factorizations of $\ u\ $ and $\ v\ $

Comment: By the way, if $\ a+b\ $ could easily be factored whenever $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ can , then we could factor every large number efficiently by applying a simple iteration, which is not the case.

Comment: One conjecture that's been getting a lot of attention recently is the "ABC conjecture", which if true contains information about the primes dividing $c$ in an equation $a+b=c$. The alleged proof of this conjecture is so complicated that essentially only the man who wrote the proof (and his colleagues) accept it. This would give you an idea as to how deep your question must lie.

Comment: @Azhao17 For factoring, this conjecture would be useless. Some diophantine equations could be solved easier or at least it could be shown for some such equations that only finite many solutions exist. But the conjecture is no technique to actually find prime factors of some integer. Concerning the status of the proof : It is a bad sign that noone except the author can understand it , the reason could well be that the proof just is not valid.